# Use Android VirtualBox Instead of Emulator for Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, virtualmachine

I want to configure my Android Jenkins projects to run a Virtualbox AndroVM instance.  I have the Virtualbox/Jenkins plugin but I don't see how to run the the VBox instance in the job, only have option to run the emulator.  Is there a way to configure Jenkins to use the VirtualBox AndroidVM to instead of the Emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Android/Android Emulator plugin for Jenkins has that feature or something similar,

You could try using the Jenkins [VirtualBox Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/VirtualBox+Plugin) or [VBoxTool](http://vboxtool.sourceforge.net/) get the instance running and set up your tests to execute from there

More info on how to configure the VirtualBox Plugin can be found in another question [What is the correct way to configure the VirtualBox plugin on Jenkins?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5399/what-is-the-correct-way-to-configure-the-virtualbox-plugin-on-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jenkins and VirtualBox, I suggest you to try [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com) Android Emulator.

Features:

- Easy to install/use
- Can use many sensors
- Can integrate with Eclipse/Android Studio
- There is a cool command line interface, where you can modify your test environment, for example sensors and battery level

A GenyMotion emulator is a VirtualBox virtual machine, so you can start/stop/suspend it like a VirtualBox machine.